# Wordpress cannot find user taxonomies on frontend

Tags: custom-taxonomy, users

I'm developing a new theme that uses user taxonomies. Users can select taxonomies through the user admin screen and save them correctly. However Wordpress only finds the taxonomies of some users on the front end. Also the taxonomy pages that filters users based on selected taxonomy is not found, so the default archives template is used instead.

**Edit:** I have tried to update my permalinks

**Have any one experienced this before?**

Here is the code i use to register one of the taxonomies:

```
register_taxonomy('Roles', 'user', array(
    'public'      =>true,
    'labels'      =>array(
        'name'                        =>'Roles',
        'singular_name'               =>'Role',
        'menu_name'                   =>'Roles',
        'search_items'                =>'Search Roles',
        'popular_items'               =>'Popular Roles',
        'all_items'                   =>'All Roles',
        'edit_item'                   =>'Edit Role',
        'update_item'                 =>'Update Role',
        'add_new_item'                =>'Add New Role',
        'new_item_name'               =>'New Role Name',
        'separate_items_with_commas'=>'Separate roles with commas',
        'add_or_remove_items'     =>'Add or remove roles',
        'choose_from_most_used'       =>'Choose from the most popular roles',
    ),
    'rewrite'     =>array(
        'with_front'              =>true,
        'slug'                        =>'author/roles',
    ),
    'capabilities'    => array(
        'manage_terms'                =>'edit_users',
        'edit_terms'              =>'edit_users',
        'delete_terms'                =>'edit_users',
        'assign_terms'                =>'read',
    ),
));
```

Here is the code i use to display the taxonomy:

```
<?php the_terms( $user->ID, 'Roles', '<bold>Roller:</bold> ', ', ', '<br>' ); ?>
```

Comment: You're using a lot of terms and permalinks here that are otherwise reserved, e.g. your archive clashes with the author archive of the user 'role', role itself is a reserved term, and you've no details on how you're displaying users. Also try to ask 1 question per question. You can always ask follow up questions about new things once it's answered

Comment: I have tried to change the name of the role back to 'skills', and deleted the terms that where saved with an association to "Roles" in the database. This still does not change anything so it might not be a problem with conflicting names. What else could it be? I'm also using Advanced custom fields, but it worked earlier also with acf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue as I see it is that you are using `the_terms` function. If you actually look in the source code you will see that after a couple of other function calls the whole thing fails because eventually the function [`get_the_terms`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/category-template.php#L1352) is called which checks if the `ID` you are passing is a valid post. Sometimes this might work though if the `user_id` might happen to match a `post_id`.

You might be interested to check the [`wp_get_object_terms`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms) function instead.

Regarding the taxonomy page problem. You are registering the taxonomy as `Roles` with capital `R`. The template file would have to contain the exact same name: `taxonomy-Roles.php`. Also, on the taxonomy page you don't have a loop. You need to query for the `object_id`, the `object` itself and then fetch users that have that association of `term_id` and corresponding `taxonomy`. You can do this with [`get_objects_in_term`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_objects_in_term).

As  **Tom J Nowell** [pointed out](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/198768/wordpress-cannot-find-user-taxonomies-on-frontend#comment289400_198768) (even though the [`documentation`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms) doesn't include the `role` term as reserved). if you have users registration enabled and if you have exotic users that would pick `roles` as the username you will get a conflict regarding the `author` query (`author_name` query variable). Due to this you may want to filter that username.

Comment: the function wp_get_object_terms was the solution. Also i cleaned up the conflicting roles name. Thank you! :)

Comment: @OleHenrikSkogstrøm Good to hear that. You also have the option to mark the answer as accepted since it is more noticeable for a visitor instead a comment I reckon.

Comment: true true. I forgot :)